Airflow TriggerDagRunOperator ignores allowed_states parameter
I've been trying to implement a master dag, that would trigger multiple dags, wait for their execution and proceed with the next tasks.
To trigger dags I used this structure:
dag3_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="demo_dag_3_trigger",
    trigger_dag_id="demo_dag_3",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    allowed_states=[State.FAILED, State.SUCCESS],
    poke_interval=5,
)

I've made a demo_dag_3 to fail all the time. It consists of one PythonOperator that executes a function:
def start_task():
    raise ValueError("I want this dag to always fail")

So, basically, I want the OPERATOR to be successful no matter, if the triggered dag run was successful or failed.
However, when I run the DAG, it triggers the demo_dag_3, which fails, then in the master dag the trigger operator fails and I have this in logs:
{{trigger_dagrun.py:209}} INFO - Waiting for demo_dag_3 on
2024-05-23T17:42:13.884946+00:00 to become allowed state ['failed',
'success']
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: demo_dag_3 failed with failed states failed

So, the logs say that airflow expects the dag to be failed or success, but still, when it fails (which should be allowed), airflow raises exception that dag failed and marks the trigger operator failed too. But I want it to be marked success.
I tried to use different options to enumerate allowed_states, I used plain_text like
allowed_states=['success', 'failed']

or states, that are available in different airflow models:
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.models.dag import DagRunState
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRunState

but sadly none worked.
How should I set up my TriggerDagRunOperators so that they will be successful even if the underlying dag is failed? Perhaps, I've misinterpreted the field allowed_states and it's just not possible to do what I want

What Airflow version are you running?

@JoshFell it's 2.7.2

If failed_states is not specified in a TriggerDagRunOperator task and wait_for_completion=True, the default is to check for a failed DAG run status of "failed" or DagRunState.FAILED. It is not possible to workaround this check at the moment.
If you need the TriggerDagRunOperator task succeed regardless of the triggered-DAG's end state, it seems beneficial to set a trigger rule on the downstream task(s) from the TriggerDagRunOperator task to allow for failures (e.g. TriggerRule.ALL_DONE, TriggerRule.NONE_SKIPPED). This way you have additional visibility into whether or not the triggered DAG failed, but your pipeline continues as you need.
